# Upper Thoracic Pain with Coughing Sensation and Slight Nausea

Tags: spine, nerves, chest, dorsal-upper-back-side

What are some possible conditions that can cause the following symptoms?

- Dull muscular pain between shoulder blades in the center of the back, in the T3-T7 region.
- Pain is often triggered or made acute by rolling the thoracic spine foreword.
- Area around T3-T7 is sensitive to light pressure. Pain appears to be immediately under the skin.
- Pain is accompanied by a sensation of needing to cough, pressure in the sternum, and on occasion slight nausea.
- Twisting the thoracic spine and shoulders left and right or side to side does not have an effect on the pain.
- On rare occasions there is a tingling or burning sensation under the left shoulder blade.
- Symptoms persist for more than 3 months, off and on.

To be clear, those are my symptoms, and I have head chest x-rays and am having an MRI done next week. The x-rays are unremarkable and 2 doctors I went to are stomped with no ideas or opinions on what it could be. I know that personal diagnosis is impossible, but I would appreciate at least a list of possible conditions to research and eliminate through further testing. Thank you!

Comment: We can't diagnose and/or give medical advice.  See your doctor.

Comment: I did mention that in the post. I have seen doctors, 2 spine specialists. They don't know. I am not asking for diagnoses, I am asking for a list of possible conditions that can cause symptoms listed above so I can do further reading or see a specialist in those conditions to eliminate them. Otherwise I am out of options.

Comment: https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor

Comment: Again, I am not asking for medical advice. I would never base my medical decisions simply on something someone said on the internet. I have I have seen 2 spine specialists, both are stumped, both have not solutions for me other than wait and see. My insurance does not cover another specialist, and quite honestly I would not know who to see. There are similar questions on this forum. I am not asking for what this IS, ia am asking for a list of ailments that would match these symptoms, so I can read up on them and talk to my doctor about them. There are similar questions on this page.

Comment: Here is an example of a similar question that has been answered with very useful information. It's not a diagnoses, but a possible future avenue of investigation. https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/ongoing-mid-upper-back-pain-causes-and-treatments

Comment: Thanks for finding that. I've flagged it for closure since it is also off topic.

Comment: Congratulations! You have just removed a useful bit of information that could have helped others with similar conditions in the future from the internet.

Comment: On the contrary, the advice given is actually incorrect, and should be removed.

Comment: When you get the results of MRI, you can bump this question again.

Comment: @Jan no, requests for personal or differential diagnosis are off topic.